# View Call Hierarchy says Cursor must be on a member name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, call-hierarchy

[I've read this great post about how to find all implementations of an interface.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261567/how-do-you-quickly-find-the-implementations-of-an-interfaces-method) However, after clicking in context menu `View Call Hierarchy`, then it says `Cursor must be on a member name`:

[image]

What I do is:

- double click at the interface
- then click `View Call Hierarchy`

[image]

How is it possible to see `View Call Hierarchy` by clicking at the interface?

Comment: The interface is never called. Hence you need a member name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is about implementations of an interface *method*. You want implementations of the interface as a whole.

Just right-click the interface and click "Go To Implementation (Ctrl+F12)", it's right there in the menu name. This will open the class if one exists, or show a list of classes if multiple implement it.